# How to fix and handle memory leak issues in Azure AppService by using IDistributedCache

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

My requirement is to generate a Report request with 100 evaluation Ids each. Report request is submitted to generate 100 Reports in PDF format or Word Format. Most of the Reports generated are about 1000 to 1300 pages each.

I have implemented ProofOfConcept on DistributedCache feature on Report data output stream for generating the Report and I was able to achieve the result. I have used this DistributedCache mechanisim to improve performance i.e. to avoid re-processing of the same Report data again when there is no change in the Report data for a certain period of time.

Also, I did test behavior of AbsoluteExpiration vs SlidingExpiration in DistributedCacheEntryOptions. I am planning to use AbsoluteExpiration option.

```
 var cacheEntryOptions = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions
  {                    
    //AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),                            
    //AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)                                                                             
      SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)                 
  };
```

Deployed the DistributedCache feature ProofOfConcept code to AppService in Azure cloud DEV environment. Below are the stats:

PDF Report:

Reportrequest submitted first time with 100 evaluation Ids in Pdf format - 100 reports processing - it takes around 28 mins.

When the Report request is again submitted with same 100 evaluation Ids in Pdf format - same 100 reports are served from Cache - it takes around 12 mins.

Word Report:

Reportrequest submitted first time with 100 evaluation Ids in Word format - 100 reports processing- it takes around 14 mins.

When the Report request is again submitted with same 100 evaluation Ids in Word format - same 100 reports are served from Cache - it takes around 1 Minute..

I was reading about Distributed Cache.
[image]

Refer the screenshot above. I was analyzing on the below use case scenarios, Need inputs and best approach to avoid any memory leak issues in the Azure environment using DistributedCache?

Example:

ReportRequest1 : generate Report request with evaluationids 1-100

ReportRequest2 : generate Report request with evaluationids 101-200

ReportRequest3 : generate Report request with evaluationids 201-300

ReportRequest4 : generate Report request with evaluationids 301-400

ReportRequest5 : generate Report request with evaluationids 401-500

ReportRequest6 : generate Report request with evaluationids 501-600

ReportRequest7 : generate Report request with evaluationids 601-700

ReportRequest8 : generate Report request with evaluationids 701-800

ReportRequest9 : generate Report request with evaluationids 801-900

ReportRequest10 : generate Report request with evaluationids 901-1000

If we do all above Report requests in span of 60 mins time, This will end up storing 1000 Reports data in the cache store.

Need inputs and best approach to handle to avoid any memory leak issues in the Azure AppService by using DistributedCache?

Thank you

Vam

Comment: Not clear where do you expect to have a memory leak here.

Comment: What I learned from online forums is the default is a simple cache that implements the distributed cache interface which is seems to be not a true distributed cache mechanism. 

suggestion is to use pick  distributed cache like  redis or sqlserver.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedi

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer

Comment: Yes, "default" is just in-memory cache in concrete app instance. It doesn't mean that there is a memory leak.

Comment: So what will be the behavior If we have all the below 10 Report requests in span of 60 mins time, This will end up storing 1000 Reports data in the Cache store.   Can a cache store supports to hold this huge data and how it clears the old data from Cache to accommodate  new Report requests which comes in ?     Trying to learn this flow  please advise

Comment: you can reproduce the distributed caching scenario, simulate report generation requests, monitor memory usage, and implement best practices to avoid memory leak issues in your Azure App Service environment. Regular testing, monitoring, and optimization are key to maintaining the stability and performance of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Guru_Stron for the given inputs.

Fixing and handling memory leak issues in Azure App Service with `IDistributedCache` involves proper resource management, setting appropriate cache expiration policies, and monitoring cache usage.

- Here, I have create Azure Cache for Redis instance in the Azure portal.

[image]

- Below console application will observe the simulated report generation and caching process using Azure Cache for Redis.

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Load configuration
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        // Configure services
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
            {
                options.Configuration = configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisCache");
                // Configure other options if needed
            })
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        var cache = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDistributedCache>();

        // Simulate report generation requests
        GenerateAndCacheReport(cache, "ReportRequest1", "evaluationids 1-100");
        GenerateAndCacheReport(cache, "ReportRequest2", "evaluationids 101-200");

        // Simulate accessing cached reports
        RetrieveCachedReport(cache, "ReportRequest1");
        RetrieveCachedReport(cache, "ReportRequest2");
    }

    static void GenerateAndCacheReport(IDistributedCache cache, string reportRequestId, string evaluationIds)
    {
        // Simulate report generation logic
        var reportData = GenerateReport(evaluationIds);

        // Cache the report data with a specific key
        cache.SetString(reportRequestId, reportData, new DistributedCacheEntryOptions
        {
            AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
        });

        Console.WriteLine($"Report {reportRequestId} generated and cached.");
    }

    static void RetrieveCachedReport(IDistributedCache cache, string reportRequestId)
    {
        // Try to retrieve the report from the cache
        var cachedReport = cache.GetString(reportRequestId);

        if (cachedReport != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Report {reportRequestId} retrieved from cache: {cachedReport}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Report {reportRequestId} not found in cache.");
        }
    }

    static string GenerateReport(string evaluationIds)
    {
        // Simulate report generation with the given evaluation IDs
        // In a real-world scenario, this would involve more complex logic and potentially fetching data from a database.

        // For simplicity, just concatenate the evaluation IDs
        return $"Generated Report for {evaluationIds}";
    }
}
```

- Iam using a Azure cache Redis. So, to leverage its eviction policies to automatically remove old or less frequently used items when the cache reaches its limits. Redis has built-in eviction policies, and I can configure them based on my requirements.

I also configured monitoring and logging to keep track of cache hits, misses, and evictions.

[image]